# needed filter a column with data for past 8 hours

Tags: obiee

I'm now working with obiee but I'm proceeding a small automation report.

I need to filter a column with set of data which has been generated before 8 hour from current time. since it is dynamic value( as it needs to generate thrice a day). I tried ((current_date) - (1/3)) and few more others queries, but I couldn't make it out. I have less time line and couldn't able to find with trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

According to OBIEE, `TIMESTAMPADD`:

> Adds a specified number of intervals to a specified timestamp, and returns a single timestamp.

You can build a column (or alter the existing column formula) to be something like this `TIMESTAMPADD(interval, expr, timestamp)` where `interval` in this case is `SQL_TSI_HOUR`, `expr` in this case is -8 (you want to go 8 hours back), and `timestamp` is the timestamp column you are referring to in your question.

If you want everything before 8 hours, you can filter on this column with a less than filter. You can also build another one of these and perform a between.

This solution does not require you to alter anything in the RPD, you only need ad hoc reporting access in OBIEE, something I am assuming you have based on your question. You are editing the formula of the column in this report only, not across the entire environment.

Comment: hi Mark,
thanks for the response but i cant change the formula for the column. i'm just automating small report for my usage.

consider we have a column A which have the data just date with timestamp, i just want to get the data which are created in that column before 8 hours from now.

kindly explain it in detail as i directly make changes in PRODUCTION

thanks & Regards,

Comment: Edited. You only need to create a new column/change a formula in the front end which you can do if you have ad hoc capabilities in OBIEE. Assuming by your question that you can access OBIEE and run reports, then you can edit columns.